# Is it possible to call an async callback with Moq when a mocked method is called?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I'm mocking some implementation using Moq and I want verify a method is called correctly on this interface, the problem is it looks something like this:

```
public interface IToBeMocked {
    void DoThing(IParameter parameter);
}

public interface IParameter {
    Task<string> Content { get; }
}
```

So I set up my mock:

```
var parameter = "ABC";
var mock = new Mock<IToBeMocked>();
mock
    .Setup(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()))
    .Callback<IParameter>(p async => (await p.Content).Should().Be(parameter));

new Processor(mock.Object).Process(parameter);

mock
    .Verify(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()), Times.Once);
```

Unfortunately, this test already passes with the following implementation:

```
public class Processor {
    public Processor(IToBeMocked toBeMocked){
        _toBeMocked = toBeMocked;
    }

    public void Process(string parameter){
        _toBeMocked.DoThing(null);
    }
}
```

Because the Callback is async but the signature requires an Action, meaning the awaiter is never awaited, and the test ends before the exception is thrown.

Is there any functionality in Moq to await an asynchronous callback?

### Edit

There seems to be some confusion. I hope this clarifies the problem.

I'm doing TDD. I've implemented the simplest shell of the code to make the test compile. Then I have written the test to ensure "ABC" is the result of the `Task` and I've set the test running. It's passing. **This is the issue**. I want the test to fail, so I can implement the 'real' implementation.

### Edit 2

The more I think about this the more I think this is probably impossible. I've opened an issue for the repo: https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/737 but I was thinking about the implementation of such a feature as I was writing the request in anticipation of submitting a PR, and it seems impossible. Still if anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them either here or in the GitHub issue and I'll keep both places up to date. For now, I suppose I will have to use a stub.

Comment: Some things don't add up in the provided example. Why the callback? What are you actually trying to test? Also the `Processor` implementation does not look correct.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks, yes, I had missed the method call. Trying to test to ensure the "ABC" string is passed to my mock via the parameter, unfortunately, the only way the string is exposed publicly is via a Task.

Comment: but you pass `null` to `DoThing`. Why?

Comment: @Nkosi because in TDD you do the simplest thing to get it to pass and write a test to force the correct implementation. My test is passing, even with my 'obviously wrong' implementation.

Comment: It is passing becuase the arranged behavior will work as configured. That call back has no effect on the test as it is on another thread

Comment: @Nkosi correct! So, the question is - how to fix the test?

Comment: I am tryin to get you to see that the issue is that the call back expects an `Action`, you attempt to perform an async operation in said callback which boils down to `async void` call. Exceptions cannot be caught in such situations as they are fire and forget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call back expects an Action, you attempt to perform an async operation in said callback which boils down to `async void` call. Exceptions cannot be caught in such situations as they are fire and forget.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

So the problem is not with the Moq framework but rather the approach taken.

Use the call back to get the desired parameter and work from there.

Review the progression of the following tests to see how the TDD approach evolves with each test.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [Test]
    public void _DoThing_Should_Be_Invoked() {
        //Arrange            
        var parameter = "ABC";
        var mock = new Mock<IToBeMocked>();
        mock
            .Setup(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()));

        //Act
        new Processor(mock.Object).Process(parameter);

        //Assert            
        mock.Verify(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()), Times.Once);
    }

    [Test]
    public void _Parameter_Should_Not_Be_Null() {
        //Arrange
        IParameter actual = null;

        var parameter = "ABC";
        var mock = new Mock<IToBeMocked>();
        mock
            .Setup(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()))
            .Callback<IParameter>(p => actual = p);

        //Act
        new Processor(mock.Object).Process(parameter);

        //Assert
        actual.Should().NotBeNull();
        mock.Verify(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()), Times.Once);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task _Parameter_Content_Should_Be_Expected() {
        //Arrange

        IParameter parameter = null;

        var expected = "ABC";
        var mock = new Mock<IToBeMocked>();
        mock
            .Setup(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()))
            .Callback<IParameter>(p => parameter = p);

        new Processor(mock.Object).Process(expected);

        parameter.Should().NotBeNull();

        //Act
        var actual = await parameter.Content;

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be(expected);
        mock.Verify(m => m.DoThing(It.IsAny<IParameter>()), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! This is what I get for programming at 10pm. I totally forgot I could just assign the parameter to the outside scope and await it there. That was the solution I just couldn't see! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It MAY or MAY NOT actually work if you use an async method signature on the callback. Depends if your runtime decides to continue with the same thread or spin up a new one.
If it makes sense, and it often does, to do some Asserts or grab some parameters for later validation in the Callback, you should remove the async stuff all together and force it to run via

`Task.Run(() => AsyncMethodHere).Result`